# How to hide the InputAccessoryView of a UIWebView on xamarin.ios/monotouch?

Tags: c#, ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Is there anyway to hide or replace the InputAccessoryView of a UIWebView on Xamarin.ios/monotouch?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you mean the cell accessory of **HtmlElement** in **MonoTouch.Dialog**.  That flexibility doesn't seem included in the implementation, but its easy to add.

Go to:
[MonoTouch.Dialog Github Source (Elements.cs)](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs)

Copy the HtmlElement class definition (Lines 527 to 640 as of this writing) and rename it to WhateverYouWantElement.  Modify the GetCell method:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
{
...
static NSString hkey = new NSString ("WhateverYouWantElement"); //very important to set a unique cell reuse identifier here!
...
cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
...
}
```

That will create a cell without the disclosure indicator.  The reuse identifier will make sure there are no conflicts with the built in HtmlElement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a subclass of `UIWebView` and overriding its `InputAccessoryView` property so it returns `null`?

```
private class CustomWebView : UIWebView      
{             
    public override UIView InputAccessoryView     
    {                 
        get                   
        {                     
            return null;                 
        }             
    }         
}      

public override void ViewDidLoad()  
{             
    base.ViewDidLoad(); 
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.                     RectangleF frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 200, 30);                          

    UITextField txfTest = new UITextField();             
    txfTest.Frame = frame;             
    txfTest.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;             
    txfTest.Placeholder = "Click here";             
    txfTest.EditingDidBegin += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {                     
        // do something             
    };

    CustomWebView webView = new CustomWebView();             
    webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(@"http://google.com")));             
    webView.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 100, 320, 480);                          
    webView.AddSubview(txfTest);                         

    this.View.AddSubview(webView);         
}
```

I tried to add an `UITextField` to an `UIWebView` but the input accessory was not shown after focusing the `UITextField`. I am using IPhone Simulator 6.1.